# Is there a convenient way to increment build numbers when building on Mobile Center?

Tags: xcode, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

Currently I'm using a build script in Xcode Build Phases:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildPlist=${INFOPLIST_FILE}
CFBundleVersion=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" $buildPlist)
CFBundleVersion=$(($CFBundleVersion + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $CFBundleVersion" $buildPlist
```

Currently the build number is getting increased on every build, not very elegant.

Is there a possibility to check if the build system is running on Mobile Center to only increase the build number then?

Can't figure it out. – Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are currently working on supporting pre- and post-build-scripts and auto-incrementing build numbers for Mobile Center soon. If there's any more clarification required, or you have specific requirements apart from the script above, feel free to contact us through the support channel in Mobile Center. We also update our [product roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/general/roadmap) regularly as a reference of the progress we are making.

Comment: I do not mean this sarcastically, but .. what is the answer to the original question - "No. It is currently not possible."? (I am not familiar with the topic. Just came across this question in the LQ "Low Quality" review queue).

Comment: I can totally see the point of providing long-lasting quality answers here - however the product this question is about is currently in public preview and there is lots of change happening every week, especially on this particular topic. So the only thing we can do is say "No we currently don't - we will soon - please talk to us in more suitable channels"?

Comment: The answer was fine with me. – Let's try to update this as soon it is possible to run build-scripts.